# How to display Images in Android on Runtime & make radio buttons as radio groups in List

Tags: java, android, listview

Updated code snipped as asked:

```
int MovieNum=children.size();  
                    String[] MovieName=new String[MovieNum]; 
                    String[] MovieCover=new String[MovieNum];                                       

                    RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup (this); 
                    rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
                    RadioButton rb[]= new RadioButton[children.size()];

                    //LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);                
                    //LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    //layout.addView(rg, p);

                    for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) 
                    {   
                        Element movieAtt = (Element)doc.getRootElement().getChild("movies").getChildren("movie").get(i);                                            
                        MovieName[i]=movieAtt.getAttributeValue( "Title" );
                        MovieCover[i]=movieAtt.getAttributeValue( "cover" );
                        ShowTime[i]=movieAtt.getAttributeValue( "showtime" );


                TweetText+=" I will see "+movieAtt.getAttributeValue("Title");
            System.out.println(TweetText);
                        //ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.rowlayout, R.id.label, MovieName);
                        //setListAdapter(adapter);
                        //String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);

                        rb[i] = new RadioButton(this);
                        rb[i].setText(movieAtt.getAttributeValue("Title"));
                        rg.addView(rb[i]);  

                        //Calling this func to get Images
                        //LoadImageFromWebOperations(movieAtt.getAttributeValue( "cover" ));

                    }                     
                }               
        } 
        catch (MalformedURLException e1) 
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("ErrorThrowedIs: "+e1);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e1.toString(),5);
        } 

    }

    public static Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) 
    {
        try 
        {
            InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
            return d;
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

//Updated code ends here

I have to display 3 things in my list View. One is going to be a Radio button corresponding to  every row. I can not use Radio group as i am not aware of the list length which is dynamically generated. So i can not set it as Radio group. 
I wish to know how can i do the same.

Also what i am doing is, i want to get an image along in the same list for every row which is created from the path i get at runtime.

So during my program, i would get these values :

```
for (int i = 0; i < mvLen; i++) 
                    {   
                        Element movieAtt = (Element)doc.getRootElement().getChild("movies").getChildren("movie").get(i);                                            
                        MovieName[i]=movieAtt.getAttributeValue( "Title" );
                        MovieCover[i]=movieAtt.getAttributeValue( "cover" );
                        ShowTime[i]=movieAtt.getAttributeValue( "showtime" );
```

Now clearly this is an string array of Movie

Names in MovieName and array of strings of URL for the cover of that movie. I wish to display all those images in front of the Movie Names. My list adapter and corrosponding XML file are listed as below. Can anyone suggest changes/hints for the same . I have been reading http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html as well. But could not figure out much to meet my requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each row in the list get the radioButton and add it to the RadioGroup.
You might have to create all the radioButton's upfront and store them in a list.Set them in the ContentView depending on the position

Answer (score 1):

So. Create RadioGroup in your class `RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(this);` and simply add radiobuttons to it when you filling content `radioGroup.addView(radioButton);`

Summary:

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(this);
//Cycle begin
      RadioButton rButton = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.my_radiobutton);
      // OR
      RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(this);
      radioButton .setText(R.string.radio_group_snack);
      radioButton .setId(R.id.snack);
      radioGroup.addView(rButton);
      radioGroup.addView(radioButton);
//Cycle end
```

Example of custom adapter and getview method(it's 100% work code):

```
    public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            String[] objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String[] users = getUsers(); //it returns list of users in String array
        LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
        View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, parent, false);
        TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.label); //TextView decalred in my layout xml file
        label.setText(users[position]);
        ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon); //ImageView decalred in my layout xml file
        byte[] bb = getAvatar(users[position]); //some method where I get image for user. It not interesting for us so I cut it from here...
        if(bb != null && bb.length != 0){
            icon.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bb, 0, bb.length)); //SET IMAGE FOR ROW
            icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //SET VISIBILITY OF IMAGE
        }
        //RIGHT HERE YOU CAN MANIPULATE WITH YOUR RADIOBUTTONS. FOR EXAMPLE:
        RadioButton rButton = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.my_radio_button);
        radioGroup.addView(rButton); //WHERE radioGroup IS RADIOGROUP YOU INITIALIZED BEFORE;
        return row;

    }

    }


}
```

And this is my onCreate method:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    db.open();
    String[] users = db.getUsersList();
    ListView listView = getListView();
    this.setListAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(this, R.layout.main, users));
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: Could not get Why you used two objects for RadioButton. The code got got bit confusing

Comment: It's just an example of adding two radiobuttons into radiogroup. Did you understand the main idea?

Comment: SO i keep on adding RadioButton in the RadioGroup in the Cycle. That i got it. But where exactly i shall implement this cycle ? In the same loop where i am extracting the MovieName and storing them in the string?

Comment: No... you didn't understand me. Let's begin from this: If you want to add image for an each row in your list you should use your custom adapter and fill list in 'getView' method. And in this method also you should add your radiobuttons to radioGroup. Is it clear? I'll give you part of my code for an example. It is doing almost the same except work with radiobuttons. See the my edited answer

Comment: @AngryBamber thanks for your help.. actually i am stuck in some other code related to the same program i am making. Still debugging it. Could not test your code. Will do it once i am done. Thanks a lot once again.

Comment: @AngryBamber I tried other thing out.. i created a RadioGroup. And on runtime i added the text for every movie to my Radio Button's text. Infact if i can just add movie cover as well it is all done for me.. i am using this approach... can you comment between both of these approaches ?

Comment: Please, type my nickname correctly (angrybambr not angrybambEr). I didn't understand exactly what do you mean. Could you post the code?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5277/discussion-between-typedef1-and-angrybambr)